# Xindy sorting of terms with square brackets

Tags: glossaries, xindy, glossaries-extra

I am looking to sort using glossaries-extra and xindy for my glossaries in lualatex. I have some acronyms that have a square bracket as part of the acronym. Is there a way to tell xindy to ignore square brackets while sorting it? See MWE.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automake,xindy,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{sa}{SA}{some acronym}
\newacronym{aa}{AA}{another acronym}
\newacronym{yaa}{[YAA]}{yet another acronym}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

which will put the acronym in square brackets first, instead of last (see picture).

[image]

Is there a way for xindy to ignore square brackets and still sort properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the optional `sort` key for this entry:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automake,xindy,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{sa}{SA}{some acronym}
\newacronym{aa}{AA}{another acronym}
\newacronym[sort=YAA]{yaa}{[YAA]}{yet another acronym}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh thank you! I tried to find some option to ignore punctuation. This is much better. Thanks!